# Create tasks programmatically in Project Server

Tags: javascript, rest, project

I need to copy tasks from one project to another in MS Project 2016 using JSOM or REST API. I used code like this:

```
function AddTaskToProjectREST(TaskToAdd) {
$.ajax({
    url:  "/pwa/_api/ProjectServer/Projects('d70c6d47-e909-45ee-b1b6-0b1c2e5e7ef3')/Draft/Tasks/Add",
    type: "POST",
    headers: {
                    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "X-RequestDigest": $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val(),
                    "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
                    "If-Match": "*"
                },
    body: {
        "parameters":
            {
                "Id": TaskToAdd.GUID,
                "Name": TaskToAdd.Title,
                "Notes": TaskToAdd.Comment,
                "Start": new Date().toISOString(),
                "Duration": TaskToAdd.DurationInBillable,
                "AddAfterId": TaskToAdd.PredeceessorGUID
            }
    },
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.d.results) {
            alert("Task added successfully");
        }
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert(xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText);
    }
});
```

}

but it returns a 403 FORBIDDEN error. I have administrator rights in PWA and I can create tasks in MS Project.
Can anyone show me a full code that creats a task in a project please?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the answer here: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Project-Samples/tree/master/Copy-Work-Packages